# Skillset needed for developing Salesforce1 mobile app

Tags: salesforce1-app

Several of my colleagues have suggested me to put forth this question in this particular forum.

Hope I am in the right place.

We are planning to develop Salesforce1 mobile app for our already existing Salesforce CRM instance.

Just wanted to get you experts' inputs as to what are the **skill sets needed for developing a mobile version** of our CRM (any pointers or links would help)

This can help us to take a call as to whether we can leverage the existing Salesforce devs (*I believe our devs already possess experience in Apex/Visualforce/HTML/CSS/Javascript technologies*) for this venture or we have to look for folks with some more specific skill sets.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all honesty: this question is way to broad, general and subjective to be a good fit to the Q&A format of this site.

Everything depends on how complex your "Salesforce CRM instance" and business processes are. To what extend are they custom or integrated with other systems ?

**The Salesforce1 mobile app IS a mobile version of your CRM**, to the extend that it supports the standard salesforce features, and still has some features that are not supported. The out of the box app can easily be extended or tailored to contain specific pages, actions,.. which is all configuration based. It's only when you want to extensivly customize certain parts some mobile/responsive HTML skills are needed in combination to the Apex/VF skills your SF devs most likely already have.

Based on your question I would recommend that you give your developers some time to explore the possibilities (and limits) of the salesforce1 app, and organise some workshops to define which processes and functioanlity are critical to have available mobile. What comes out of those steps will give you more insight than anyone on an online forum can give you.

Answer (score 1):

Expertise in Apex/Visualforce/HTML5/CSS3/Javascript/jQuery/jQueryMobile and Javascript mobile frameworks like Angular is a good start. It will be very good if you can get someone with experience in phonegap, iOS and Android SDKs

UPDATE - Since it was mentioned in the question as "Develop Salesforce1 Mobile app", I thought it is regarding extending the app through coding. But if user want to customize standard salesforce1 app without coding, any of the above skills are not needed. But customizations that can be done without coding in Salesforce1 mobile app is limited.

Comment: "/jQuery/jQueryMobile and Javascript mobile frameworks like Angular" I believe these are all open source...but   "phonegap"..this I believe is proprietary..am I not right ?..does this mean that we have to pay for this additional s/w also ?..just curious

Comment: Phonegap is free and opensource. Please check http://phonegap.com/about/license/ . You will not need to use phonegap directly. You will be using it through salesforce mobile sdk. Please check https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK

Comment: I completely disagree with this answer. It's very incomplete and doese not take into consideration that a lot of the salesforce CRM comes out of the box in the Salesforce1 mobile app which can easily by extended with configuration.

Comment: Sorry about that since it was mentioned in the question as "Develop Salesforce1 Mobile app", I thought it is regarding extending the app through coding. But if user want to customize standard salesforce1 app without coding, any of the above skill are not needed. But customizations that can be done without coding in Salesforce1 mobile app is limited.

Comment: BTW: If you could elaborate on that in your question, I can remove my downvote. It won't let my if there's no edit

Comment: Updated my answer to accommodate standard SF1 app features.

Answer (score 1):

Another something to look at is the Lightning tool. https://www.salesforce.com/form/conf/platform-overview.jsp It leverages your existing elements.

If you attend a dreamforce local, they are able to walk you through this process. They have you bolt together an example in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

For create any custom components on SF1 you must use Lightning Components. Lightning based on Aura UI Framework. So for develop something on SF1 you must know how work with Aura.
http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs